# My widget doesn't show on the mainwindow. qt

Tags: c++, qt, widget

in my program the senario is like this, user opens a xml file, the program reads it. Show the units and tests and when the user clicks on the desired test, the program needs to show its step. Since the number of steps always change i need to add the widget by code and delete them. But when i try to add a widget by code and set its position it doesn't show up on the main window. ( i am doing this with a seperate class just make things look neater)

Here is my sample code;

```
  void CStepPanel::addstep()
      {
           QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("step1");
           label1->move(450,50);


       }
```

Do you know doesnt it work ? And how can i do that. Since i am new to qt and programming i am having a hard time about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget should have a parent to be shown in an other widget or dialog. You should set a parent for the label. If you want it to be displayed on the main window then a pointer to your `QMainWindow` should be kept in the class `CStepPanel` (It could be assigned in the constructor of `CStepPanel`) :

```
QMainWindow * mainWindow;
```

And the `addstep` is like :

```
QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("step1");
label1->setParent(mainWindow);
label1->move(450,50);
```